# Getting properties of widgets from a glade file

Tags: c, gtk, glade

I'm new to GTK and C. I started making UI for the embedded system. The interface should represent several tabs with information, switching between which is carried out by buttons on the device itself or by JS commands from a paired device (server). I am trying to implement this with GTK and Glade. I got a problem while using GtkStack. I need to pass the name of the stack page to the server so that the server sends back the information that will be displayed on the page.
I tried to get the Name of the page from the glade file using the function `gtk_widget_style_get`, but the compiler issues a warning `../gtk+-3.24.27/gtk/gtkwidget.c:13324: widget class 'GtkStack' has no property named 'title'` and the program displays "garbage" instead of the page name. I also tried to get the "label" of the button. `gtk_widget_style_get(btn_1, "title", &temp, NULL)` The result was the same.

Here is the test code I am experimenting with

main.c

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

#define UI_FILE "for_test.glade"

GtkBuilder      *builder;
GtkWidget       *window;
  GtkWidget     *stack;
    GtkWidget   *fix_1;
      GtkWidget *lbl_1;
      GtkWidget *btn_1;
    GtkWidget   *fix_2;
      GtkWidget *lbl_2;
      GtkWidget *btn_2;

void
on_btn_1_clicked(GtkWidget *widget)
{
  gchar *temp[100];
  gtk_widget_style_get(stack, "title", &temp, NULL);
  gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(lbl_1), *temp);  
}

void 
on_window_destroy()
{
  gtk_main_quit();
}

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  gtk_init(&argc, &argv);
  
  builder = gtk_builder_new_from_file(UI_FILE);
  
  window = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "window"));
    stack = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "stack"));
      fix_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fix_1"));
        lbl_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_1"));
        btn_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "btn_1"));
      fix_1 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "fix_1"));
        lbl_2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "lbl_2"));
        btn_2 = GTK_WIDGET(gtk_builder_get_object(builder, "btn_2"));
  
  g_signal_connect(window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(on_window_destroy), NULL);
  g_signal_connect(btn_1, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_btn_1_clicked), NULL);
  //g_signal_connect(btn_2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK(on_btn_2_clicked), NULL);
  gtk_builder_connect_signals(builder, NULL);
  
  g_object_unref(builder);
  gtk_widget_show(window);                
  gtk_main();
  
  return 0;
}
```

for_test.glade

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Generated with glade 3.38.2 -->
<interface>
  <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.24"/>
  <object class="GtkWindow" id="window">
    <property name="can-focus">False</property>
    <property name="default-width">100</property>
    <property name="default-height">200</property>
    <signal name="destroy" handler="on_window_destroy" swapped="no"/>
    <child>
      <object class="GtkStack" id="stack">
        <property name="visible">True</property>
        <property name="can-focus">False</property>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkFixed" id="fix_1">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="btn_1">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button 1</property>
                <property name="width-request">100</property>
                <property name="height-request">80</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives-default">True</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_btn_1_clicked" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="y">100</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbl_1">
                <property name="width-request">100</property>
                <property name="height-request">80</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="name">page0</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">page0</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
        <child>
          <object class="GtkFixed" id="fix_2">
            <property name="visible">True</property>
            <property name="can-focus">False</property>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkButton" id="btn_2">
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">button 2</property>
                <property name="width-request">100</property>
                <property name="height-request">80</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">True</property>
                <property name="receives-default">True</property>
                <signal name="clicked" handler="on_btn_2_clicked" swapped="no"/>
              </object>
              <packing>
                <property name="y">100</property>
              </packing>
            </child>
            <child>
              <object class="GtkLabel" id="lbl_2">
                <property name="width-request">100</property>
                <property name="height-request">80</property>
                <property name="visible">True</property>
                <property name="can-focus">False</property>
                <property name="label" translatable="yes">label</property>
              </object>
            </child>
          </object>
          <packing>
            <property name="name">page1</property>
            <property name="title" translatable="yes">page1</property>
            <property name="position">1</property>
          </packing>
        </child>
      </object>
    </child>
  </object>
</interface>
```

I suspect that I am using the wrong function to get the properties of the stackab page, but I haven't found another way to get them. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: you can set the label of a button using gtk_button_set_label - read up on the details here: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html#gtk-button-set-label. so, basically you would use gtk_builder_get_object to retrieve the button or window and then set the label or the title

Comment: @muzzletov Thanks, but I needed to do a little different. The solution was suggested by a work colleague. Here it is:
  ```
  GValue k = {0,};  
  g_value_init(&k, G_TYPE_STRING);
  gtk_container_child_get_property(GTK_CONTAINER(stack), fix_1, "name", &k);
  g_message("%s", g_value_get_string(&k));
```

Comment: Oh, I see. xD I assumed you had a different goal in mind. Would you mind adding an answer, so people can benefit from your findings?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the solutions:

```
GValue k = {0,}; 
g_value_init(&k, G_TYPE_STRING); 
gtk_container_child_get_property(GTK_CONTAINER(stack), fix_1, "name", &k);
g_message("%s", g_value_get_string(&k));
```